# SAPUI5 Object Page Header Image Click

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I've an image in my Object Page Header. And I need to show the full image inside a popup when click on the header image.

Is there any event to fire when click on the image. I've checked the API reference & unable to find one.

```
<uxap:ObjectPageHeader id="headerForTest" objectTitle="{i18n>Number} {ArticlePage>/SelectedObj/Title}" showTitleSelector="false"
                                titleSelectorPress="handleTitleSelectorPress" showMarkers="false" markFavorite="false" markLocked="false" markFlagged="false"
                                markLockedPress="handleMarkLockedPress" isObjectIconAlwaysVisible = "true"  >                                   
                                
                            </uxap:ObjectPageHeader>
```

Comment: See this answer:
[Preview Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650766/sapui5-uploadcollection-preview-image-in-same-window/66650817#66650817)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Avatar** tag with the **detailsBox** aggregation as mentionned below:

```
<m:Avatar src="./test-resources/sap/m/images/284133_GettyImages-145058106_2600.jpg" displaySize="XL" imageFitType="Cover" press="onPress"
                    badgeIcon="sap-icon://camera" badgeTooltip="Sabine Mayer" class="sapUiLargeMargin">
                    <m:detailBox>
                    <m:LightBox>
                        <m:LightBoxItem
                                imageSrc="test-resources/sap/m/images/274827_274827_l_srgb_s_gl.jpg"
                                alt="Michael Adams"
                                title="This is Michael Adams"
                                subtitle="Michael Adams Human Relations">
                        </m:LightBoxItem>
                    </m:LightBox>
                </m:detailBox>
                </m:Avatar>
```

Comment: how to insert this code without affecting the current layout, I've updated my question