# SapUI5 UploadCollection Preview Image in same window

Tags: javascript, image, sapui5

I am using the SapUI5 UploadCollection to upload Images from users as recommended in
[UploadCollection Samples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection)

Problem is when clicking on the image it opens in a separate new window.
Is there any way to show a preview of the image in the same window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SapUI5 Lightbox control allows users to view an image in its original size. The control displays the image in a popup while dimming the rest of the screen.

By using the press event for the UploadCollectionItem you can show a LightBox preview of the image as follows:

```
<UploadCollectionItem press="onUrlPress" thumbnailUrl="{ProductPhotos>UrlThumb}" url="{ProductPhotos>Url}" >


 onUrlPress: function (oEvent) {
        var item = oEvent.getSource();
        var url = item.getProperty("url");
        this.lightbox = new LightBox({
            imageContent: {
                title: url,
                imageSrc: url
            }
        });
        this.lightbox.open();
    },
```